# RxJS- How to access the value of a BehaviorSubject after operations

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

Say I have a behavior subject, piped through an operation or two:

```js
const inputNumber = new BehaviorSubject(2);

// The current number can be retrieved with `inputNumber.getValue()`

const numberAfterOperations = inputNumber.pipe(
  filter(a => (a+1) % 2), // filter out odd numbers
  map(a => a * a), // square it
);
```

**How can I access the value of numberAfterOperations?**

```js
// Does not work because `getValue` is not defined!
numberAfterOperations.getValue(); // I expect this to be 4

inputNumber.next(4);

// Does not work!
numberAfterOperations.getValue(); // I expect this to be 16
```

> Note: the observable subscription here works fine. I'm asking about synchronous access to the `.value` (or `.getValue()`)

I noticed a similar issue here, but did not see a resolution:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2378

Comment: To be clear, you are not piping the `BehaviorSubject` itself, only it's value. Thus, the value of `inputNumber` will not be updated in the `map(a => a * a)` and it sounds like that's what you're expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, folks. You have helped me realize that there is no built-in way to do what I wanted with behavior subjects. I wound up with the following:

```js
function mapBehaviorSubject(behavior, mapFn) {
  const mappedSubject = new BehaviorSubject(mapFn(behavior.getValue()));
  behavior.subscribe({
    next: value => mappedSubject.next(mapFn(value)),
  });
  return mappedSubject;
}
```

This allows me to have the desired behavior:

```js
const inputNumber = new BehaviorSubject(2);

const numberAfterOperations = mapBehaviorSubject(inputNumber, x => x * x);
```

This allows me to have a persistent subject with the mapped value available synchronously with `getValue()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused about how Observables/Subjects work. The Subject doesn't hold the value of 4 or 16 in the examples you've shown, those are *derived* by applying your piped operations through the resulting observables. You'll have to use an operator like `first()` or `take(1)` to get the value out in between calls to `next` on the Subject. The Subject only knows about the values that have been sent through it with `next` it has no knowledge about how observables that may be attached to it decide to modify that value.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe sets up a new observable that doesn't do anything until it is subscribed to. It is not a behavior subject that the value can just be accessed with getValue. You have to subscribe to it or it is a cold observable and there is no data going down the stream at all. Put a console.log in your map function and you will see that it doesn't even get called if there is no subscription.

You could write an unwrap function if you are 100% sure that the subscription will run synchronously as it will if derived from a BehaviorSubject but if you pass in an asynchronous observable the results will be unpredictable, most likely returning undefined.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;
const { filter, map } = rxjs.operators;

const inputNumber$ = new BehaviorSubject(2);

const numberAfterOperations$ = inputNumber$.pipe(
  filter(a => (a+1) % 2), // filter out odd numbers
  map(a => { console.log('mapping'); return a * a; }), // square it
);

inputNumber$.next(4);

console.log('No mapping has happened yet');

console.log(unwrap(numberAfterOperations$));

function unwrap(obs$) {
  let value;
  const sub = obs$.subscribe(val => { value = val; });
  sub.unsubscribe();
  return value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

If you are using Angular you can use the async pipe in the view

```
{{ numberAfterOperations | async }}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Observable.pipe()` returns `Observable`, thus if you want to have access to the actual `BehaviourSubject`, you must pass it too.

```
const inputNumber = new BehaviorSubject(2);

// The current number can be retrieved with `inputNumber.getValue()`

const numberAfterOperations = inputNumber.pipe(
  filter(a => (a+1) % 2), // filter out odd numbers
  map(a => a * a), // square it
  map(n => [n, inputNumber])
);

// ...later

numberAfterOperations.subscribe(([number, subject]) => {
  sbject.next(n/2);
});
```

But this should not be done, you can clearly see the anti-pattern. Make `.next` into a separate method and import it where needed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this:

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

const inputNumber = new BehaviorSubject(2);
const numberAfterOperations = inputNumber.pipe(
  filter(a => (a+1) % 2), // filter out odd numbers
  map(a => a * a), // square it
);

// as root source is a BehaviourSubject this will resolve immediately with actual value
await firstValueFrom(numberAfterOperations);
```

But opinionated advice: Please double question yourself, if this imperative way is a good idea when working with declarative rxjs, or if there is a cleaner solution